# How to highlight text in QTextEdit/QSyntaxHighlighter using solorized colors?

Tags: qt, qtextedit

[My app](http://leoeditor.com/) would like to fully support the [solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) color scheme. To do this, we would like to use the dark theme for selections, and the light theme for non-selected text, something like [this](http://www.phpstorm-themes.com/sites/default/files/Screen-Shot-2012-12-06-at-3.17.48-PM.png).

My question is this: is it possible (without writing low-level code Qt Paint code) to highlight selected text in a QTextEdit (colorized using QSyntaxHighlighter) so that the selection background color changes, but the multiple different foreground colors in the selected region remain unchanged?

Thanks.

Comment: At worst, you'd be changing the syntax highlighter code, no need to write any Qt painter code. Qt comes with sources: use them, you're supposed to!

Comment: Leo's [colorizer](https://github.com/leo-editor/leo-editor/blob/master/leo/core/leoColorizer.py) is, in fact, a complete Python rewrite of QtGui.QSyntaxHighlighter.The problem does not appear solvable at this level. Indeed, pqsh.setFormat calls QtGui.QTextLayout.FormatRange(). The problem is, how to get the desired the desired selection colors? I *have* studied this problem, and it seems that a custom Painter may be the only way.